# CiviCRM Upgrade after 4.0: do I need to update civicrm.settings.php?

Tags: drupal, upgrade

From the CiviCRM Upgrade for Drupal wiki article, step 9 indicates that all versions 4.0 or after require editing the civicrm.settings.php file, and provides two options to accomplish this.

> CiviCRM 4.0 and above requires definitions in civicrm.settings.php which previous versions of CiviCRM did not have. There are two methods to put these required definitions into your install:
>
> Create a "dummy" database and install CiviCRM fresh into that. You will need to rename or move your existing civicrm.settings.php. Running the installer anyhow will automatically create a correct civicrm.settings.php file. Then either replace that dummy database with your real one and proceed with the upgrade OR edit the new civicrm.settings.php to point to your real database.
>   Add the definitions manually to your civicrm.settings.php file as below:
>
> If your civicrm.settings.php does not have this section, copy and paste from here into civicrm.settings.php: [settings follow]

If the upgrade is starting from a version that is already 4.x, can we completely skip step 9 or what is the recommended way to handle this step?

https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Upgrading+CiviCRM+for+Drupal+7

Comment: Those instructions sound misleading. I'm pretty sure they are trying to say that any upgrade from a version less than 4.0 to more than 4.0 need to add those values - i.e. they were added/required at the beginning of the 4.x series.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, those settings should already be in your civicrm.settings.php - but it would only take a moment to check your file and ensure the values on the wiki page are there.